# Register keys pressed from another class in GLFW3

Tags: c++, input, glfw

I'm having trouble getting key input to manipulate a few variables in a class. The static function `key_callback` below belongs to the lastest version/example of **[GLFW3](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/quick.html).** I have a rendering class with basic camera coordinates, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to connect my cam and yaw-pitch-roll variables to be updated when keys are pressed.

I've tried moving the static function into my Renderer class, tried making my cam variables static, but nothing worked.

Within **Renderer.h**

```
GLfloat camX, camY, camZ, yaw, pitch, roll;
```

Within **main.cpp**

```
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE:
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE); <-- Works
            break;
        case GLFW_KEY_W: camZ += 0.1f; break; <-- What I'm trying to get
        case GLFW_KEY_S: camZ -= 0.1f; break;
        case GLFW_KEY_A: camX += 0.1f; break;
        case GLFW_KEY_D: camX -= 0.1f; break;
        case GLFW_KEY_E: yaw += 0.05f; break;
        case GLFW_KEY_R: yaw -= 0.05f; break;
    }
}
```

Within **int main()**

```
GLFWwindow* window;
Renderer rend;
....
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
rend.Initialize();
(Main loop)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with callbacks, and the way I was able to resolve it was not particularly elegant, however i did the following (translated to match your codes names, and assuming your code is correct):

in the same file as your main:

```
static void getKeyInput(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    key_callback(window, key, scancode, action, mods);
}
```

in the actual main function:

```
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, Renderer::key_callback);
```

replaced by:

```
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, getKeyInput);
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way of doing it (but I don't believe it's the best way by far).

With the function still in **main.cpp,** I made a separate Camera class all together with the basic getters and setters for the camera's x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll.

So from there (since I can't use my Renderer class outside of int main()), I did this:

```
(includes)...
Camera cam;

static void getKeyInput(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{ 
    GLfloat delta = 0.0f;
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE:
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
        break;
    case GLFW_KEY_W: 
        delta = cam.getZ();
        delta += 0.1f;
        cam.setZ(delta);
        break; 
    ....

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    Renderer rend;
    ...
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
```

Then within the main loop I changed the Render function to be overloaded:

```
    rend.Render(cam.getX(), cam.getZ(), cam.getYaw());
```

Keys work now, but the only issue I see with my solution is that movement isn't instantaneous when the key is first pressed.